# Insufficient Priviliges to click Rename Tabs and Labels option under customize in salesforce?

Tags: permissions, customlabel

I am trying to update some labels in Sales force but do not have access to the "Tab Names and Labels" options at the following click path: Your Name | Setup | Customize | Tab Names and Labels.

Does anyone know if there is a setting I need to change to gain access to this option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing View Setup and Configuration checkbox as checked under profile of the user you are using to gain access.

Administrator | Manage Users | Profile under this path find your profile and check the chechbox (View Setup and Configuration).

Happy Coding.

Comment: in my profile (System Administrator) that View Setup and Configuration check box is already checked... but i didn't get access for that option                     Tab Names and Labels.

Comment: There is one more check box customize application under administrative permission
Check this checkbox. Sorry for late reply.
I hope this might work.

Comment: in my profiles both options checked under Administrative Permissions...            Any other way to gain access to Tab Names and Labels Option...